# Is there a jQuery plugin or JavaScript code to allow client-size image resizing/cropping in a circle?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, imagemagick, php-gd

We're trying to allow the user to select the exact face of a person from a chosen photo and we want to achieve this by providing an oval shape into which the user has to fit the face by resizing the photo or the oval itself.

Is there any plugin I can use or will this need to be done from scratch?

Comment: You can probably do it with a canvas element, but it will be quite a learning curve if you're starting from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know of a plugin (and google is a better place for this) but it's not hard to develop one. Just create a overlay div with some opacity over the image the user sent. Then use jQuery UI draggrable and resizable for a smaller div with transparent background.

Send the div's position, width and height to the server and perform the cropping there.

Comment: Do you know of any existing jQuery image cropping/resizing plugin that allows custom mask overlays? I tried looking around for that, but I didn't come up with much.